# What are eigenfunctions in a box which includes two kinds of medium?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

I have to solve a problem of mathematical physics. There is a simple case which can inspire me to solving a more complex case.

Considering a metal box in 2D $0<x<a$ and $0<y<b$. And there are two kinds of medium, $0<x<c$ and $c<x<a$ with different dielectic constants $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$, respectively.

I want to solve the equation 
$$\nabla (\epsilon \nabla \phi) = -Q\delta (x-c)\delta(y-\frac{b}{2})$$
where $\epsilon = \epsilon_1$ if $0<x<c$ and $\epsilon = \epsilon_2$ if $c<x<a$

There is an electric charge $Q$ at $x=c$ and $y=\frac{b}{2}$, then what the distribution of potential is in this case?

How do I write the eigenfunctions in this condition?

It is easy to write the eigenfunction in two different area, $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$. 
$\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ satisfy $\nabla^2 \phi_1 = - \frac{Q}{\epsilon_1} \delta (x-c)\delta(y-\frac{b}{2})$ and $\nabla^2 \phi_2 = - \frac{Q}{\epsilon_2} \delta (x-c)\delta(y-\frac{b}{2})$ respectively.

Could I combine two parts directly with conditions $\phi_1|_{x=c}=\phi_2|_{x=c}$ and $\epsilon_1 \frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial x}|_{x=c} = \epsilon_2 \frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial x}|_{x=c}$ to get the eigenfunctions in the box?

Are these functions complete?

Comment: Eigenfunctions of what?

Comment: @Ruslan the Eigenfunctions in the box, which satifies the Poisson's equation. The charge is on the surface between two kinds of medium.

Comment: Eigenfunctions are not "eigenfunctions somewhere" — they are _eigenfunctions of an operator_. I.e. the eigenfunctions are such functions that satisfy $\hat Lf=\lambda f$, where $\hat L$ is an operator and $\lambda$ is eigenvalue associated with $f$. What operator are you considering? Laplacian?

Comment: @Ruslan I know what you said, I mean the "eigenfunction somewhere" as eigenfunction satisfied a boundary condition. Here I think there are bad boundary conditions which the inhomogeneous term only appears on the boundary. I don't know how to solve the equation in this case.

Comment: @Ruslan I have edited the question. How to solve the equation? Because $\epsilon$ is not the same anywhere, I think I have to solve the equation in two part area and then connect the two eigenfunctions as the eigenfunction in the whole area. I want to know I am right or wrong and why. Thanks!

Comment: It seems you're confusing solution of the Poisson equation and solution of eigenproblem. There're infintely many eigenfunctions, but [only one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_theorem_for_Poisson's_equation) solution of Poisson equation given the boundary conditions. Which of these do are you trying to find?